# Merging thousands of rasters without downloading images

Tags: raster, gdal, merge

My AOI has about 8262 1m DEM files (7 GB size). I want to merge these files without downloading these images from https://elevation.fsdf.org.au/ using gdal.

Is there a way to merge thousands of rasters without downloading the images?

Comment: What real difference would it make to download the set, and then to combine them, than to request them to be combined before downloading?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to combine raster files without downloading 7GB of data.

Comment: But you will still need to download the 7GB after they have been merged, no?

Comment: Yep thanks you are right. I was thinking of any solution where I don't have to download multiple thousand of multiple images but only one merged piece, but I guess it is impractical. Thanks.

Comment: It may not be impractical, if it is possible, I was just curious about the reason for attempting it.

Comment: Try to upload the data file to online service provider and do the processing there, then download. you have to use JavaScript or Python to do this as well as might have to do some payments for the services they are providing

Comment: Not sure if that's what you want, but you can easily mosaic remote files to create a virtual GDAL raster with gdalbuildvrt, provided you have a stable URL for the remote (e.g.) GeoTIFFs. It is convenient to extract small spatial windows without downloading all the data.